# Proj4 projection supports WebGLPointsLayer but throws GeoJSON polygons off

Tags: openlayers, geojson, proj4js

In order for the following WebGLPointsLayer

```
    this.layer = new WebGLPointsLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        url: "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson",
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        attributions: 'USGS'
      }),
   })
```

to render within the correct extent in a map that has a view center shifted to [103.8198, 0], I am configuring the following custom proj4 projection

```
proj4.defs('sphmerc180', '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=103.8198 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs');
register(proj4);

var sphmerc180 = getProjection('sphmerc180');
sphmerc180.setExtent(getProjection('EPSG:3857').getExtent());
sphmerc180.setGlobal(true);
```

and then writing the view like so:

```
this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: this.layers,
  view: new View({
    projection: 'sphmerc180',
    center: fromLonLat([103.8198, 0], 'sphmerc180'),
    zoom: 1
  })
});
```

This works nicely to shift the WebGLPointsLayer from this extent:

[image]

into the expected extent:

[image]

However, this technique wreaks havoc on this [GeoJSON polygon layer I'm using from Natural Earth](https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/blob/master/geojson/ne_10m_geography_regions_polys.geojson):

[image]

which otherwise renders normally with the center shift to [103.8198, 0] without the custom proj4 projection. I understand that some polygon coordinates are being sent round the world, which is why many polygons are rendering that way.

What is the best way to accommodate both of these layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike transforms between built in global projections (EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326) those involving proj4 don't wrap in the same way so instead of wrapping where the geojson intended at the date line it is splitting somewhere else and distorting the polygons where they cross that line.  That is an issue that OpenLayers should fix as it can cause other problems but until then a quick fix would be to define a custom transform which goes between your custom projection and lon/lat via EPSG:3857 and adds or subtracts the appropriate offset

```
var offset = transform([0,0], sphmerc180, 'EPSG:3857')[0];
var to3857 = getTransform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
var from3857 = getTransform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

addCoordinateTransforms(
  sphmerc180,
  'EPSG:4326', 
  function(coordinate) {
    var input = coordinate.slice();
    input[0] -= offset;
    return from3857(input);
  },
  function(coordinate) {
    var output = to3857(coordinate);
    output[0] += offset;
    return output;
  }
);
```

Comment: In thinking about your answer, I'm wondering if it makes more sense not to use proj4 on the Map View, which transforms all of the map layers, but instead use it only on the WebGL points layers as these are the only ones that need it. Is that possible in OpenLayers?

Comment: I took the proj4 projection transformation off of the map view and tried instantiating the WebGLPointsLayer vector source with `format: new GeoJSON({
        dataProjection: sphmerc180,
        featureProjection: sphmerc180
      }),` and got the now-dreaded pileup of points only at the view center.